# Sage Pay Forms Refund and Authorisation

Tags: php, opayo

I have ingerated the forms payment method it all works fine. But I'm looking for a way to allow refunds/authorisations to be processed from my site, rather than having to go to Sage Pay to do it.

I found some code which relates to the Sage Pay direct method. This seemed to work, until I realised I wasn't getting the Security Code back from Sage Pay when I placed a form order.

Is there any way to either get the security code? or another way to process refunds without going to the Sage Pay site.

Thanks for any help! I'm pretty new when it comes to Sage Pay.

Comment: You'd probably do better asking Sage Pay themselves - have you tried that? In my (limited) experience they have excellent support.

Comment: Hi Rup, I haven't asked them directly, but I did ask on there forums and got no response. If I don't find anything some though I will contact them, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I send a question into Sagepay as Rup suggested.

This service isn't available with the Forms integration only the Direct and Server methods.

Answer (score 0):

Refunds from your front end system **do require** Sage Pay's SERVER or DIRECT integration.  The securty key is ONLY passed back during these integration methods.

If you are using FORM then refunds are carried out in the My Sage Pay interface.